# Animation for imageView(fade)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, fade

How to create a fade in ImageView to change it to other image (i.e. from Image 1 to Image 2) when imageView is clicked and vica versa

I have created another click method but it is not working because i think as I have already put image-2 aplha to 0.

```
public void fade(View view)
{

    ImageView mickey=findViewById(R.id.mickey);
    ImageView mouse = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    mickey.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    mouse.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question - are you asking how to reverse the above animation?

Comment: I think you could try with the Picasso library : https://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple `method` to play around with: :)

```java
boolean firstImage = false;
    private void fadeFlip(View view) {
            AlphaAnimation aa = new AlphaAnimation(1f,0f);
            aa.setDuration(1*1000);
            view.startAnimation(aa);
            aa.start();
            if(firstImage) {
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else { 
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_2);
            }

            AlphaAnimation bb = new AlphaAnimation(0f,1f);
            bb.setDuration(1*1000);
            view.startAnimation(bb);
            bb.start();

            firstImage = !firstImage;
    }
```